# PHP and mySQL Task Scheduler program and database theory?

Tags: php, mysql, scheduling, computation-theory

I need to develop a website that runs jobs at certain times (every 15 minutes) I'll use a cron to run the webpage.

What is the best way to store the jobs information in? Some jobs will be daily, others every 8 hours etc. To complicate matters, I also need to take into consideration the timezone differences. This shouldn't be too difficult as PHP has many timezone functions, but how do I integrate it in the programming of the next job to run?

Another question, is how will the user enter the information for the jobs to run? One option, similar to http://www.webcron.org, is to ask the user to select how often the jobs must run, but how do I store that info in a database?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the crontab syntax, store it in a DB and run a separate crontab invoking the execution script every minute.

There are GPL classes that do that for you already, like : http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4140-PHP-Database-driven-PHP-job-scheduler-like-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a [MySQL Event](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html), that will take care also the storing, recurrence, execution.